# How to extract element from JSON stringify

Tags: javascript

How to extract value of element from JSON stringify?
Below is the sample JSON string.

```
{"resultCount":3,"results":[{"value":"abc","Content-Disposition":"form-data","name":"\"appKey\""},{"value":"123","Content-Disposition":"form-data","name":"\"userName\""},{"value":"test1","Content-Disposition":"form-data","name":"\"password\""}]}
```

I want to extract below values from above json string
abc
123
test1

Comment: Why would you stringify an object if you wanted to extract data from it?

Comment: You might need to stringify an object to send it somewhere, and then parse it again as data.

Answer (score 2):

The "opposite" of JSON.stringify is JSON.parse. It will return you a JavaScript object with that structure. To get your strings, you'd want to do:

```
var data = JSON.parse("... your string ...");
data.results.map(function(obj) { return obj["value"]; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values in an array or you can get them in separate variables.

```
var json = { "resultCount": 3, "results": [{ "value": "abc", "Content-Disposition": "form-data", "name": "\"appKey\"" }, { "value": "123", "Content-Disposition": "form-data", "name": "\"userName\"" }, { "value": "test1", "Content-Disposition": "form-data", "name": "\"password\"" }] };
var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++)
{
  newArr.push(json.results[i].value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose var x contains this whole JSON stringify parsed value like var x = JSON.parse[{},{}]

Then to extract values you can use like this :

```
for(i=0; i<x.results.length; i++){
     console.log(x.results[i].value);
}
```